# Delphi datasnap send an from image to server (to be stored in database)

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have searched high and low for a working solution for sending an image (e.g. tpngimage) to the server using a datasnap method - but I cannot make it to work.

When I load the image and save it to a memorystream, I'm able to read the image back from the stream - locally in the client, which is not really a surprise. But when the server method gets called, the stream is nil and contains nothing, the other parameters are fine (simple datatype and an object).

Did I miss something obvious here? I was under the impression that TStream is a valid datatype for datasnap methods, but maybe I'm wrong?

The from client side it looks like this.

```
function TPerson.Update: Boolean;
var
  AStream : TMemoryStream;
  APicture : TPngImage;
  ASize : Integer;
begin
  if (FId > 0) then // if Id below zero we have a problem
  begin

    ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.UpdatePerson(Self);
    APicture := TPngImage.Create;
    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      // Temp just use a file
      AStream.LoadFromFile('.\images\075.png');
      ASize := AStream.Size;
      AStream.Position := 0; // wind back if needed

      // just for testing, we can read back the image from the stream
      APicture.LoadFromStream(AStream);

      ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.UpdatePersonPicture(self, ASize, AStream);

    finally
      FreeAndNil(AStream);
      FreeAndNil(APicture);
    end;

  end;
  FModified := False;
end;
```

And the proxy method looks like this

```
procedure TServerMethods1Client.UpdatePersonPicture(APerson: TPerson; ASize: Integer; APictureStream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  if FUpdatePersonPictureCommand = nil then
  begin
    FUpdatePersonPictureCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
    FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
    FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Text := 'TServerMethods1.UpdatePersonPicture';
    FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Prepare;
  end;
  if not Assigned(APerson) then
    FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetNull
  else
  begin
    FMarshal := TDBXClientCommand(FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Parameters[0].ConnectionHandler).GetJSONMarshaler;
    try
      FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetJSONValue(FMarshal.Marshal(APerson), True);
      if FInstanceOwner then
        APerson.Free
    finally
      FreeAndNil(FMarshal)
    end
    end;
  FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Parameters[1].Value.SetInt32(ASize);
  FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.Parameters[2].Value.SetStream(APictureStream, FInstanceOwner);
  FUpdatePersonPictureCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
end;
```

The Server method looks like this - it fails due to the APictureStream is nil.

```
procedure TServerMethods1.UpdatePersonPicture(APerson: TPerson; ASize: integer;
  APictureStream: TMemoryStream);
var
  APicture : TPngImage;
begin
  fdqPersons.Close;
  fdqPersons.SQL.Clear;
  fdqPersons.Connection.StartTransaction;
  try
    fdqPersons.SQL.Add('update Persons set Picture=:Picture ');
    fdqPersons.SQL.Add('where Id=:Id');
    fdqPersons.ParamByName('Id').Value := APerson.Id;

    APicture := TPngImage.Create;
    try
       // APicture for testing - but APictureStream is nil!
       APicture.LoadFromStream(APictureStream);
       fdqPersons.ParamByName('Picture').Assign(APicture);
       fdqPersons.ExecSQL;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(APicture);
    end;
    fdqPersons.Close;
    fdqPersons.Connection.Commit;
    LogEvent(format('Person picture updated ID: %d',[APerson.id]));
  except
    on e:exception do
    begin
      fdqPersons.Connection.Rollback;
      LogEvent(format('Error updating person picture %s',[e.Message]));
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: On the client side, nothing is being done with `APicture`, although that's not your issue. In reality, you're not "sending a `TPngImage` " as your question describes. You're simply sending a file.

Comment: Yes, I have tried different solutions, it doesn't matter for now if it's a file or an image. I would just like to get some stream data.

Now, interesting enough, I just have removed this line client side...
      APicture.LoadFromStream(AStream);

And vupti - now there are available data on the server side....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `APicture.LoadFromStream(AStream);` the stream's position goes to the end, and therefore when passing it into `ClientModule1` it does not have any data left to be read. Either get rid of the unnecessary portion where you write the stream to a `TPngImage` or reset the stream's position back to 0 just after that part.